# adding hours in date time format java

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date time1 = parser.parse("7:30");
```

Now if I want to add 2 more hours to `time1`, like:

```
7:30 + 2 = 9:30
```

how do I add the 2 hours?

Comment: If the answer helped you, do accept that particular answer.

Answer (score 7):

`java.util.Date` is deprecated, you should use `java.util.Calendar` instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date myDate = parser.parse("7:30");
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2); // this will add two hours
myDate = cal.getTime();
```

And even better solution is to use [Joda Time - Java date and time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

From their website - ***Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes.***

Comment: No `java.util.Date` is *not* deprecated, though several of its methods are. But both .Date and .Calendar should be avoided, now supplanted by the java.time class.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `java.util.Date` into `java.util.Calendar` Object and use [**Calendar.add()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method to add Hours

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date time1 = parser.parse("7:30");
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(time1);
cal.add(Calendar.Hour_Of_Day, 2);
time1 =cal.getTime();
System.out.println(parser.format(time1));//returns 09:30
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "07:30" ).plusHours( 2 )
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( " Pacific/Auckland" ) )
    .plusHours( 2 )
```

## java.time

The old date-time classes such as java.util.Date, .Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat should be avoided, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

For a time-of-day only value, use the `LocalTime` class.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "07:30" );
LocalTime ltLater = lt.plusHours( 2 );  
String output = ltLater.toString();  // 09:30
```

### `Instant`

For a given `java.util.Date`, convert to java.time using new methods added to the old classes. The `Instant` class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Or capture current moment in UTC as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Add two hours as seconds. The `TimeUnit` class can convert hours to seconds.

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds( 2 );
Instant instantLater = instant.plusSeconds( seconds );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

To view in the wall-clock time of some community, apply a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

You can add hours. The `ZonedDateTime` class handles anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusHours( 2 );
```

### `Duration`

You can represent that two hours as an object.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 2 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```